# Pythonic way of creating a subset of a dict without creating copies of the elements

Tags: python

I have a program whose front end pre-loads all the renderable objects into a dict. The front end also holds a list of the subset of objects which should currently be rendered to the screen.

The back end pushes a list of the objects keys for the objects which should currently be rendered. It also pushes any any changes in their position.

The front end then populates the render list by taking the server list of render keys and selecting the appropriate objects from the pre-loaded dict.

This means on each update I am creating a new copy of all the currently renderable objects which is resource intensive. Alternativly if I only push an incremental update with new objects to be added, any changes in position to existing objects have to be pushed both to the pre-load dict and the current render list.

What I am working around is that I really want my render list to hold pointers to the objects in the pre-load dict. Is there a way to do this? Or is there a more pythonic solution to this issue?

```
//server data is list of lists with format [obj_key, x, y]  
//eg: [[146,10,10]]


//Front End  
def __init__(self):  
       self.manifest = { 146 : renderobj1, 395 : renderobj2 }  
       self.render_list = [ ]  

def update(self,server_list):  
       self.render_list = [ ]  
       for server_item in server_list[]:  
           self.manifest[server_item[0]].x = server_item[1]  
           self.manifest[server_item[0]].y = server_item[2]  
           self.render_list.append(self.manifest[server_item[0]])
```

This code works but creates copies of all objects to be rendered on each update.

I want a way for the render_list to hold pointers to the objects to be rendered or a more pythonic solution please.

Comment: Unlike in some other programning languages an assignment (`=`) in Python creates references and no copies.

Comment: Where do you get the idea that objects get copied? See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html for some information on how names work in Python.

Comment: Comments in Python start with `#` not `//`, btw.